# How to let content scroll without going over my header?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm new to webdesign and i have a little problem. I have a header(at the top), a navigation(at the left) and then the main content. I have set my header and navigation to position: abosulute so it won't scroll with the page. Now I wanna make it that the maincontent doesn't go over the header when you scroll. How can i do this?

[image of the site](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/823/93876703.png/)

Comment: set the main container div position:relative

Comment: check my answer and let me know if am lagging some where..

Comment: @jochemke - if my answer is correct so please mark it correct...

Comment: If my answer is correct then you can mark it correct so in future some one will come on this page and he/she will get the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the fiddle to get the desired layout... `Header and sidebar position: absolute;`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FTtzc/1/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FTtzc/1/embedded/result/

Comment: If my answer is correct then you can mark it correct so in future some one will come on this page and he/she will get the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Put the main content in a container of its own and give that container a scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

Give your Header a Backgroundcolor and `z-index: 2;` and your content gets `z-index: 1;` 
for further reference on z-index http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: The problem with z-indexes is that part of the scrollbar goes behind the elements that are on top. Simply putting the elements side by side works better in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your content in another absolutely positioned div, and then allow it to have a scrollbar with `overflow: auto` (scrollbar hidden when not necesssary) or `overflow: scroll` (scrollbar always visible).

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/YYmA9/1/